# how to check image size less then 100kb android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am trying to get image from gallery and setting up it on `ImageView` , Hear is okay well i get and set image on `ImageView`, but now i want to check image size of selected image in `kb` so i set the validaion for image uploading.
Please anyone can suggest me how to check selected image size less then `100kb` or not?, 
Hear is my code for image selecting and setting it.

Choosing Image useing `Intent`

```
 Intent iv = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(iv, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and get Image Result code ..

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        ivLogo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            uploadNewPic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

to know the size is less then 100kb. you should know the image size to compare. there is some method to know the size of bitmap

**method 1**

```
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher);


 Bitmap bitmap = bitmapOrg;
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   
 byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray(); 
 long lengthbmp = imageInByte.length;
```

**method 2**

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/Your_file");
 long length = file.length() / 1024; // Size in KB
```

**For more Study**

go for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount%28%29

Comment: in method 1 you are not checking the file size after compressing so i feel its wrong

Answer (score 7):

Get file size as

```
File img = new File(picturePath);
int length = img.length();
```

it will return size in bytes. you can convert byte into kb

Answer (score 0):

```
   ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> newFilePath = new ArrayList<>();  //for storing file path which size is less than 100 KB

    if (imagePaths != null) {
        filePaths.addAll(imagePaths);
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(filePaths.get(i));
            int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));     //calculate size of image in KB
            if (file_size < 100)
                newFilePath.add(filePaths.get(i));  //if file size less than 100 KB then add to newFilePath ArrayList
        }
    }
```

Here `imagePaths` stores path of all images that we have selected. Then if `imagePaths` is not null then add all images path in `filePaths`. You can use this code for document type of file also.

Answer (score 0):

Just input URI from the intent and get the size of any file

```
uri = data.getData();
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.e("TAG", "Name:" + returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        Log.e("TAG","Size: "+Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
```

It will give size in bytes, So 100kb will be 100000bytes. I think this will help you.